# sed multiple pattern matches in a line

Tags: sed

I'm trying to write a sed command to convert lines:

```
<http://dbpedia.org/resource/BoA> <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/wikiPageWikiLink> <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Ne-Yo> .
<http://dbpedia.org/resource/BoA> <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/wikiPageWikiLink> <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Tablo> .
```

to

```
BoA, Ne-Yo
BoA, Tablo
```

I know how to match and print using /(/) but I can't find a way to print two matches.

Comment: You need awk for that. Posting what you've already tried also helps.

Comment: `awk` will provide a more elegant and sustainable solution IMHO.

Answer (score 1):

Using `awk` you can do:

```
awk -F"[/>]" '/http/ {print $5 ", " $15}' file
BoA, Ne-Yo
BoA, Tablo
```

Answer (score 0):

Use parentheses and then `\1` to print the first match, `\2` to print the second match, and so on.

```
sed 's|<http://dbpedia.org/resource/\([^>]\+\)> <[^>]\+> <http://dbpedia.org/resource/\([^>]\+\)>.*|\1,\2|g' input.txt
```

A little verbose, though. Put your text into `input.txt` file.

Answer (score 0):

Less verbose, but also less accurate than @rendon's solution:

```
sed -e 's?.*/resource/\([^>]*\)>.*/resource/\([^>]*\).*?\1, \2?' input.txt
```

If it's good enough then this is more readable.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -r 's|[^>]*/([^>]*)>.*/([^>]*).*|\1, \2|' file
```